# Split and rename large folder/files

Tags: python, directory, dataset

I have a folder with 20000 images and I need to separate them into 1000 folders with 20 images in each, in addition I also need to rename the folders and files to the following structure:

```
│   ├── video_00000

...│   │   ├── frame_00000.jpg

...
│   │   ├── frame_xxxxx.jpg


│   ├── video_xxxxx
```

Would anyone have a suggestion on how to do this optimally using Python?

Comment: you should look into os module and shutil.

Comment: Make a small program to generate a shell script, review it and run. To be safe, use `mv -n` (Linux) to rename files.

Comment: What's the specification?